# set the char array to all zero values (in C)

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, character, array-initialization

How can I set the vars array to all zero '0' values?

```
typedef char array_t[100];

void
setvars(array_t vars[], int lens[]) {
/*vars : 10 numbers
lens : the length of 10 numbers in vars
*/
.
.
.
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use loop or `memset`. Please don't ask how to do that.

Comment: Your typedef for `array_t` is almost certainly not what you want.  In particular, you cannot pass that type by value, since it will "decay" into a `char *` when used as a function argument.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [`memset()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/):

```
void
setvars(array_t *vars, size_t num, size_t *len) {
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        memset(vars[i], 0, len[i]);
    }
}
```

where `num` is the length of `len`.